# Using sequelize transactions with nested then()

Tags: node.js, express, transactions, sequelize.js

I read all the transaction doc in sequelize at this link : https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html
And search multiples solutions in google, but I don't find the exact solution I need.

So my problem is I'm trying to use nested transactions with sequelize, I wanna execute all the query only if all successed. So this is what I tried : ***(this is a minimized version of the actual code to improve your reading experience)***

```
try {
    await db.sequelize.transaction(async (t1) => {
        const promises = Promise.all(
            Object.keys(DefaultLicencesConfigurations).map((defaultLicenceConf) => {
                const licenceConfDefault = DefaultLicencesConfigurations[defaultLicenceConf]

                return LicencesConfigurations.create(
                         {Param} // Just for the example to make the code smaller, 
                         {transaction: t1})
               .then((licenceConf) => {
                        return licenceConf
                    })
            })
        )

        promises.then((licenceConf) => {

            UserRoles.findOne({where:{role:UserRolesTypes.ARTIST}}).then(async (role) => {
                    await db.sequelize.transaction({
                        transaction: t1
                    }, async (t2) => { // It seem the code is bloqued here
                        Users.update(
                            {ID_user_role: role.id}, 
                            {
                                where: {id: artist.ID_user},
                                transaction: t2
                            })
                            .then((user) => {
                                // Code didn't come here
                                console.log(user)
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                // If i console.log() here it show the console log so it's catched
                            })
                    })
                })
        })
    })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

So what I'm doing wrong here ? I'm using differents transactions, but the second transaction (t2) is still catching an error. And if I completly remove the transaction (t2), it's work correctly, but we lose the utility of transactions because the code will be executed even if the transaction fails.

------------- EDIT ---------------------------------------------

I created a new method for this promise all part, but the problem is when I have an error in my t5 transaction with the LicencesArtists, the promise is resolved anyway, and the LicencesConfigurations is created anyway. Any solutions ?

```
const createLicencesConfiguration = async (artistID, transaction) => {
    return await db.sequelize.transaction({ transaction }, async (t4) => {
        return await Promise.all(
            Object.keys(DefaultLicencesConfigurations).map(async (defaultLicenceConf) => {
                const licenceConfDefault = DefaultLicencesConfigurations[defaultLicenceConf]

                const licenceConf = await LicencesConfigurations.create(
                    {
                        name: licenceConfDefault.name,
                        default_price_dollars: licenceConfDefault.default_price_dollars,
                        limit_copies_sales: licenceConfDefault.limit_copies_sales,
                    },
                    { transaction: t4 }
                )

                if (!licenceConf) {
                    return null
                } else {
                    return await db.sequelize.transaction({ transaction: t4 }, async (t5) => {
                        return await LicencesArtists.create(
                            {
                                ID_artist: null /*artistID*/ // I do that for generate an error,
                                ID_licence_configuration: licenceConf.id,
                            },
                            { transaction: t5 }
                        )
                    })
                }
            })
        )
    })
}
```

He did the **rollback** in the insert part for licences_artists but he **commit** at the end, why ?

```
Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): INSERT INTO `licences_artists` (`ID_artist`,`ID_licence_configuration`) VALUES (?,?);Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05-sp-1`;
Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05-sp-2`;
Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05-sp-3`;
Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05-sp-4`;
Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05-sp-5`;
Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05-sp-5`;
Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05-sp-5`;
Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT `54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05-sp-5`;
Executing (54f84ba7-7cde-450a-92e1-d5f9326fcd05): COMMIT;
```

Comment: This mix of `await`s and `then`s looks really messy. Can you use only `await` and make your code more straightforward and linear?

Comment: I edit the post to make the code more readable thank's !

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait when t2 is finished in t1. Use `await` like this:

```js
    try {
        await db.sequelize.transaction(async (t1) => {
            const licences = await Promise.all(
                Object.keys(DefaultLicencesConfigurations).map((defaultLicenceConf) => {
                    const licenceConfDefault = DefaultLicencesConfigurations[defaultLicenceConf]

                    return LicencesConfigurations.create({
                        }, {
                            transaction: t1
                        })
                        .then((licenceConf) => {
                            return licenceConf
                        })
                }
            ));

            const role = await UserRoles.findOne({
                    where: {
                        role: UserRolesTypes.ARTIST
                    }
            })
            await db.sequelize.transaction({ transaction: t1 }, async (t2) => {
                const user = await Users.update({
                        ID_user_role: role.id
                    }, {
                        where: {
                            id: artist.ID_user
                        },
                        transaction: t2
                    })
            })
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```